# Modify Existing Join Programmatically in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, join

I have a View in ORACLE with many tables, and joins. I need to modify the join from table 'A' to table 'B' to link to a different field (column) in table 'B'. Can I do that using sql? Unfortunately, I don't have access to the sql that initially created the view, or I would just change the join there.

Comment: What do you mean you don't have access to the SQL that created the view?  You should be able to generate the DDL that created the view.  SQL Developer, TOAD, and pretty much any GUI should be able to generate the DDL when you right click on an object.  You could use the `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` function if you want a way to generate the existing DDL at the command line.  You'd then want to modify that DDL manually to update the view definition.

Comment: A view is just a stored query. It doesn't have properties that can be modified independently. Use dbms_metadata as Justin suggested to recover the original SQL so that you can modify it.